# React Native (Expo) not working cause child objects rendering, although I am only rendering strings

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I have a problem not many people have on internet.
The thing is: App worked on my old OS (Windows) and when i switched to new (Reinstalled Linux) this error below pops up when i try to build (actually render app on Expo Go). I am mentioning OS cause that may be problem but idk what, code is code.

After installing all modules and checking if it can be built I get this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {apiLogin}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This error is located at:
    in RCTText
    in TouchableText (created by Text)
    in Text (created by LoginPage)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by NativeViewGestureHandler)
    in NativeViewGestureHandler (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by LoginPage)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by LoginPage)
    in LoginPage (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
```

Now, This error in react appears when you wanna render object instead of string. But I am not rendering any objects as only objects. Hel :p

Also, why all modules, I do have, have this error?

Comment: Embed your code

Comment: The problem is you are rendering an object inside your Text component. Check it again